# How make a 'core' repository in Github? I need make dependencies

Tags: git, github, dependencies, repository

I have a repository with a code in C that is designed as a **core code**, it is so basic that it works for various embedded devices.
I would like to use that core in several more specific device repositories and that these repositories have a dependency on this 'core repository'.

I have been seeing that there are tools like **submodules**, however it is not useful to me because these core files should be directly in the root of the repository.

I would like to know if there is a tool in git or Github that has been designed for this type of application.

Thank you very much.

Comment: That sounds like it should be implemented as a library. Git is not a very good library distribution mechanism.

Comment: the problem is that my team uses Github. I have to find some way not to rewrite code...

Comment: Can you give more context on the constraint "these core files should be directly in the root of the repository" ?

Comment: @LeGEC yes, the idea is have an repository C core with files like: - main.c - lib.c - lib.h - and generical code like that, and several repositories of devices with: - Makefile (in root) and one specific folder, for example /ESP32 with others archives, and that all these devices repositories share the same main.c lib.c, etc of the core repository

Comment: Thanks for the details ; you can add them to your original question -- you will have an easier time formatting the text than in a comment.

Comment: So, *technically*, you *could* have these files in a subdirectory (say `core/`), couldn't you ? it's just about conventions of where to find the files in a C project, or am I missing some point ?

Comment: thanks guys, resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with `subdirectory` Git feature.
Thanks